# Private DNS behind Palo Alto is not resolving Name Servers

Tags: azure, dns, nameservers

We are using private DNS zones for our internal sites. We are connected to the cloud by site to site vpn on palo alto and until recently our private domains have stopped resolving and name servers are not finding their way. Using dig command I am able to cache some of the addresses on palo alto but they get deleted right away but not all so for now I have added static entries for DNS proxy but the issue is that anything behind a load balancer or with wild card is not working.
Is there a work around to  this as this seems to be a bug of palo alto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### edit

In your scenario of resolution of Azure hostnames from on-premises computers, the private DNS zone could not help, you need to use your own DNS server for the internal name resolution in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances). Then you need forward queries to your DNS proxy server in the corresponding virtual network, the proxy server forwards queries to Azure for resolution, see use [name resolution by your own DNS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server).

[image]

Comment: I already have a vpn gateway stie to site but I am not able to resolve my custom private domain app.something.io or anything *.something.io

Comment: note: when i am on vpn everything is working smoothly.

Comment: Could you show your network topology? Are all private DNS zone failure?  Is the DNS could not resolve from your on-premise network to Azure VNet? or between Azure VNets? Is it a temporary issue?

Comment: Yeah its on-premises that I cant resolve DNS and yeah all dns fail if I dont add the static entry on dns proxy on palo alto.